# BST node deletion in c

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

i'm trying to delete the nodes of a BST of strings that don't have a certain char in a certain position, but the code seg-faults and i can't trace the source of the error.

the inserting phase does the job, it's the deleting part that gives me headaches.
the delete function finds the key in the tree then deletes the node containing that key.
any help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct BST {
    char *value;
    struct BST *p_left;
    struct BST *p_right;
};

typedef int (*Compare)(const char *, const char *);

int CmpStr(const char *a, const char *b)
{return (strcmp (a, b));}

//function to insert words into string
void insertInTree(char* key, struct BST** leaf, Compare cmp) {
    int res;
    if( *leaf == NULL ) {
        *leaf = (struct BST*) malloc(sizeof( struct BST ) );
        (*leaf)->value = malloc( strlen (key) +1 );
        strcpy ((*leaf)->value, key);
        (*leaf)->p_left = NULL;
        (*leaf)->p_right = NULL;
    } else {
        res = cmp (key, (*leaf)->value);
        if( res < 0)
            insertInTree(key, &(*leaf)->p_left, cmp);
        else if( res > 0)
            insertInTree(key, &(*leaf)->p_right, cmp);
    }
}

//helper function to find the min value string in alphabetical order
char* minValueNode(struct BST* node) {
    struct BST* current = node;
    while (current->p_left != NULL)
        current = current->p_left;
    return current->value;
}

//function to delete the node in the BST
struct BST* deleteNode(struct BST* root, char *key) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return NULL;
    int cmp_result = strcmp(key, root->value);
    if (cmp_result < 0)
        root->p_right= deleteNode(root->p_right, key);
    else if (cmp_result>0)
        root->p_left= deleteNode(root->p_left, key);
    else{
        if (root->p_left == NULL && root->p_right == NULL){
            free(root);
            return NULL;
        }
        else if (root->p_left==NULL) {
            struct BST *temp = root->p_right;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        } else if(root->p_right==NULL){
            struct BST *temp = root->p_left;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else {
        char *newMin = minValueNode(root->p_right);
        strcpy(root->value, newMin);
        root->p_right= deleteNode(root->p_right, newMin);
        }
    }
    return root;
}

//function to check if there is the exactchar char in the n position in the string 
void charInExactPosition(struct BST *head, char exactchar, int n)
{
    if( head != NULL ) {
        charInExactPosition(head->p_left, exactchar, n);
        if (head->value[n]!=exactchar){
            deleteNode(head, head->value);}
        charInExactPosition(head->p_right, exactchar, n);
    }
}

void printTree(struct BST *root)
{
    if( root != NULL ) {
        printTree(root->p_left);
        printf("%s\n", root->value);
        printTree(root->p_right);
    }
}

int main(){
    struct BST* tree = NULL;
    insertInTree("AAAAA", &tree, (Compare) CmpStr);
    insertInTree("AkdAA", &tree, (Compare) CmpStr);
    insertInTree("AAfAA", &tree, (Compare) CmpStr);
    insertInTree("AdgAA", &tree, (Compare) CmpStr);
    insertInTree("AhAAA", &tree, (Compare) CmpStr);
    insertInTree("AAAiA", &tree, (Compare) CmpStr);
    insertInTree("2AAAA", &tree, (Compare) CmpStr);
    charInExactPosition(tree, 'A', 1);
    printTree(tree);
}
```

Comment: Since the sentence of death for a single node has been decided by `charInExactPosition`, what's all the weirdness about comparing keys in `deleteNode`... Clean up the code and re-post the question, please... It's not worth anyone's time trying to figure out `deleteNode` as it obviously does not do what you think it does...

Comment: do you think i should put the deletion of the nodes right into the `charInExactPosition` function? that could simplify the deletion process because i don't have to find the node since i'm already in it... can you explain me what's the problem with the `deleteNode` function?

Comment: Trouble with deleting nodes once you're AT the node to be deleted is updating PARENT nodes... Right now, `charInExactPosition` calls the executioner, but doesn't "mend" the tree... You need to review BST algorithms with pencil and paper before coding it... This code looks like you have been racing to score a goal without doing the field work necessary... `malloc()` can fail, returning NULL. Why do you cast the first malloc, but not the second? It's your code, and I don't want to get a headache trying to follow it... Sorry...

Comment: Keep things simple! You should create a `delete` function that does only delete a node. Nothing else. Then you can call it from your `charInExactPosition` function and from a new wrapper function `hasExactValue` that picks the node based on `head->value`.

Comment: You don't care about return value of `deleteNode` in `charInExactPosition`. If there were no children to that node, you keep a dangling pointer. Also as you only pass `tree` and not `&tree` you can never clean all the tree making `tree=NULL` again

Comment: Um... Maybe I'm not reading this right, but... your insert logic builds the tree in lexicographical *ascending* order; e.g. a node's left children are "less" (<), and right children are "greater" (>)  .But your delete hunts for the node by traversing *right* on "less", and left on "greater". that's gonna lead to never finding the node you seek unless you happened to land on it at root from inception. Unrelated, modifying *anything* in the node structure of retained nodes *besides* the node pointers in a basic tree is an instant code smell (looking at you, `strcpy(root->value, newMin);` ).

Comment: @WhozCraig Ah, but!... Once that string has been copied, the hunt goes on to expunge the node whose value was copied... Funny... `:-)`

Comment: @Gerhardh As `WhozCraig` points out, this 'implementation' is fundamentally based on a string "key"... So, as I had written, "passing around a ptr to a comparison function that is simply `strcmp()` only muddies the waters..." "Minimal reproducible example"...

Comment: @Fe2O3 I admit I did kind of chuckle at that myself.

Comment: There are 3 more issues: 1) You never free memory for `value`, causing a memory leak. 2) You reserve memory for `value` based on the key you add to the tree but then you copy `newMin` into the `value` of current root which could have a totally different length. 3) You use the `cmp` function correctly for inserting a key into the tree. But then you use `strcmp` to search the node to delete. You must use a `cmp` function there as well.

Comment: @Gerhardh Good clues. Nice. However, the 'strcpy()', in this case, is a red herring as all the 'keys' are the same length, so copying should fit without overrun... But, you're onto something! :-)

Comment: @Gerhardh thank you for the answer, that's a mess... at least the 2) i don't think it's a problem, the strings have a fixed lenght

Comment: If you plan to use same length always, then you should make it an array. No need to `malloc` and `strlen` then. And no need to `free` afterward. If you want to keep it flexible, do it right. ;)

Comment: @Gerhardh yeah, the strlen got left in there. i can't use an array because i don't know at the beginning how many strings i'm going to insert in the data structure and i need the strings to be in order, and using a linked list is mad time inefficent (it would been a lot easier tho)

Comment: I mean an array inside your struct instead of a `value` pointer.